# Why are the old bars still visible after transition

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a D3 barchart which has 5 bars. When I update it I can see it transitioning to the correct 3 bars but some of the original bars are left visible - how do I make them exit?

This is what it initially looks like:

[image]

This is what it ends up looking like:

[image]

The dark blue bars are correct. The current code for updating the "rect" objects is the following:

```
var plot = d3.select("#barChartPlot")
  .datum(currentDatasetBarChart);

/* Note that here we only have to select the elements - no more appending! */

plot.selectAll("rect")
  .data(currentDatasetBarChart)
  .transition()
  .duration(750)
  .attr("x", function (d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .attr("width", width / currentDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding)
  .attr("y", function (d) {
    return yScale(+d.measure);
  })
  .attr("height", function (d) {
    return height - yScale(+d.measure);
  })
  .attr("fill", colorChosen);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have 3 new bars, so the number of elements on your data has changed.
You need to use the [update pattern](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218).

```
var rects = plot.selectAll("rect")
  .data(currentDatasetBarChart);

  rects.enter()
   .append("rect")
    //Code to style and define new rectangles.

  //Update 
  rects.update()
  .transition()
  .duration(750)
  .attr("x", function (d, i) {
    return xScale(i);
  })
  .attr("width", width / currentDatasetBarChart.length - barPadding)
  .attr("y", function (d) {
    return yScale(+d.measure);
  })
  .attr("height", function (d) {
    return height - yScale(+d.measure);
  })
  .attr("fill", colorChosen);

  // Remove unused rects
  rects.exit().remove();
```